# Efficient way to subset and combine arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, scipy

Given a 3 dimensional boolean data:

```
np.random.seed(13)
bool_data = np.random.randint(2, size=(2,3,6))

>> bool_data 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

I wish to count the number of consecutive 1's bounded by two 0's in each row (along axis=1) and return a single array with the tally. For `bool_data`, this would give `array([1, 1, 2, 4])`.

Due to the 3D structure of `bool_data` and the variable tallies for each row, I had to clumsily convert the tallies into nested lists, flatten them using `itertools.chain`, then back-convert the list into an array:

```
# count consecutive 1's bounded by two 0's
def count_consect_ones(input):
    return np.diff(np.where(input==0)[0])-1

# run tallies across all rows in bool_data
consect_ones = []
for i in range(len(bool_data)):
    for j in range(len(bool_data[i])):
        res = count_consect_ones(bool_data[i, j])
        consect_ones.append(list(res[res!=0]))

>> consect_ones
[[], [1, 1], [], [2], [4], []]

# combines nested lists
from itertools import chain
consect_ones_output = np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(consect_ones)))

>> consect_ones_output
array([1, 1, 2, 4])
```

Is there a more efficient or clever way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a trick to pad the columns with zeros and then look for ramp-up and ramp-down indices on a flattened version and finally filter out the indices corresponding to the border ones to give ourselves a vectorized solution, like so -

```
# Input 3D array : a
b = np.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,0),(1,1)), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0))

# Get ramp-up and ramp-down indices/ start-end indices of 1s islands
s0 = np.flatnonzero(b[...,1:]>b[...,:-1])
s1 = np.flatnonzero(b[...,1:]<b[...,:-1])

# Filter only valid ones that are not at borders
n = b.shape[2]
valid_mask = (s0%(n-1)!=0) & (s1%(n-1)!=a.shape[2])
out = (s1-s0)[valid_mask]
```

**Explanation -**

The idea with padding zeros at either ends of each row  as "sentients" is that when we get one-off sliced array versions and compare, we could detect the ramp-up and ramp-down places with `b[...,1:]>b[...,:-1]` and `b[...,1:]<b[...,:-1]` respectively. Thus, we get `s0` and `s1`  as the start and end indices for each of the islands of `1s`. Now, we don't want the border ones, so we need to get their column indices traced back to the original un-padded input array, hence that bit : `s0%(n-1)` and `s1%(n-1)`. We need to remove all cases where the start of each island of `1s` are at the left border and end of each island of `1s` at the right side border. The starts and ends are `s0` and `s1`. So, we use those to check if `s0` is `0` and `s1` is `a.shape[2]`. These give us the valid ones. The island lengths are obtained with `s1-s0`, so mask it with valid-mask to get our desired output.

Sample input, output -

```
In [151]: a
Out[151]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])

In [152]: out
Out[152]: array([1, 1, 2, 4])
```

Comment: Incredible solution! However, even after studying the scripts, I still don't understand the logic at work here. For instance, what's the purpose of getting ramp-up and ramp-down indices? Why `s0%(n-1)%(n-3)` -- also, where do the '-1' and '-3' come from? Lastly, what's the reasoning for (s1-s0)[valid_mask]?

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!! I'm still working out the details and hope to understand all of it soon.

Answer (score 2):

> consect_ones.append(list(res[res!=0]))

If you use .extend instead, the content of the sequence is appended directly. That saves the step to combine the nested lists afterwards:

```
consect_ones.extend(res[res!=0])
```

Furthermore, you could skip the indexing, and iterate over the dimensions directly:

```
consect_ones = []
for i in bool_data:
    for j in i:
        res = count_consect_ones(j)
        consect_ones.extend(res[res!=0])
```